# Google App Engine Federated Authentication - migrate from OpenID2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, google-oauth, google-openid

We have an application deployed in production environment running on Google AppEngine with python2.7 and NDB.

It uses the Federated Authentication via OpenID implemented according this article: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/openid

The [Users API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass) from AppEngine is used for authentication (e.g. `users.get_current_user()`, `users.create_login_url(federated_identity='https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id')` for Google login, etc.) - exactly as it is described in the main.py under **Examples** section in the article above.

Recently we are receiving a message during authentication:

> OpenID 2.0 for Google accounts is going away.
>   Developers should migrate to OpenID Connect by April 20, 2015. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6135882).

I see that there is a documentation for "Migrating to OpenID Connect (OAuth 2.0 for login)" at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#openid-connect

Probably every single person who uses Federated Authentication on AppEngine will face now the problem of migration... and will need to preserve the user data bound to the existing user identifiers which the Users API provides.

We must preserve the usage of Users API - as it is used all over the application.

Does Google plan to offer an alternative to the single line code `users.create_login_url(federated_identity='https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id')` on AppEngine to make the port easier?

Is there an example source code of how to migrate the Federated authentication on AppEngine in Python to the new OpenID Connect?

Is there a compatibility layer for Users API with Federated authentication planned to be provided?

Comment: I had a glimpse at https://github.com/scotch/engineauth/, but this brings completely new authentication system and does not seems to use Users API, which is otherwise available in the Federated Authentication.